# Skip or delete lines between two keywords in a file using python

Tags: python, logic, pyth

The problem is I need to skip or delete all the lines between the two keywords in a file and the keyword pair will appear many times in the file.The file looks something like this

```
.
.
..........
..........
Hello world
..........
..........
welcome
.
.
.
..........
..........
Hello world
..........
..........
welcome
.
.
.
.........
.........
Hello world
..........
..........
welcome
.
.
.
..........
..........
```

Here the contents between Hello world and welcome are to be deleted (including those keywords). Please help me out with this.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Please note that this site is for challenges, not general questions on programming. You may want to ask your question on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) instead.